# Self Start function in R

Tags: r, regression, self

I'm trying to fit a non linear regression for mosquito development respect to temperature that I got from a paper but the author did not established a function. Moreover to set the nonlinear regression I'm using the first model stated by breier et al (1999) :

rate of development (1/days) = a*Tpred*(Tpred-TO)*sqrt(TL-Tpred)  for TO<Tpred<TL

where a is a constant
Tpred is the temperature to use as predictor of rate of development
TO is the temperature when development is zero
TL is the lethal temperature

data is:

Temp: 15, 20, 25, 30, 35

rate_to_adult:0.028571430, 0.06944444, 0.09615385, 0.11363636, 0.08130081.

and my code following the Ritz book non linear regression with R

```
model_function<-function(Tpred,a,TO,Tl){a*Tpred*(Tpred-TO)*sqrt(Tl-Tpred)}
#function   for the model

model_initial<-function(mCall,LHS,data){
xy<-sortedXyData(mCall[['Tpred']],LHS,data)
fit<-lm(xy[,'y']~xy[,'x'])
coefs<-coef(fit)
a<-coefs[1]    
TO<-coefs[2]
Tl<-coefs[3]
value<-c(a,TO,Tl)

names(value)<-mCall[c('a','TO','Tl')]
value
}

Self_starter<-selfStart(model_function,model_initial,c('a','TO','Tl'))

print(getInitial(rate_to_adult ~ Self_starter(Temp,a,TO,Tl), param), digits = 3)
```

the previous line generates:

0.00300  0.00299   NA

for a, TO and Tl respectively

and
m1<-nls(rate_gon ~ Self_starter(Temp,a,TO,Tl), data = param)

generates: Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]],names(ind), env) :
Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the mod

What do I have to modify to actually get the starting values (all of them) and model fit?

## Update

From comment:

> I plot the data and a curve to start trying values for each parameter as

```r
 g<-function(Te,a,TO,Tl){(a*Te*(Te-TO)*sqrt(Tl-Te))} # rate to adult model (evaluating starter values)

plot(rate_to_adult~Temp, data = param, xlim = c(0,50), ylim = c(0,1)) 

curve(g(x, a=0.00007,TO=8, Tl=37), add = TRUE)
```

> [I]t did not take long to find appropriate ones for a TO and T1 checking the behavior of the curve respect to the points. Then just use `nls()` and got the parameters which were pretty close

Comment: I don't think you have enough data to make a sensible fit.

Comment: Are you attached to using a self starting model?  For `TO` and `Tl` I would just graph the data to get an idea for starting values, and use the default of 1 for `a` as a first try.  Based on the equation, if `Tl` isn't bigger than the value of `Temp` you'll get an error (square root of a negative number).  I agree with @Carl Witthoft that the dataset seems terribly small for this.

Comment: Hey thanks. As complement for readers, I plot the data and a curve to start trying values for each parameter as 
g<-function(Te,a,TO,Tl){(a*Te*(Te-TO)*sqrt(Tl-Te))}

# rate to adult model (evaluating starter values)

plot(rate_to_adult~Temp, data = param, xlim = c(0,50), ylim = c(0,1))

curve(g(x, a=0.00007,TO=8, Tl=37), add = TRUE)

Luckily in this case I guess, it did not take long to find appropriate ones for a TO and T1 checking the behavior of the curve respect to the points. Then just use nls() and got the parameters which were pretty close